# Sibling div is inside of other sibling div

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in the top of my website with this css:

```
.menu {
width: 100%;
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

inside of it, I have few divs:

```
.menu .menu-item {
position: relative;
width: 260px;
float: left;
height: 430px;
}
```

This is all good, but when I try to add a small div underneath the menu, with this HTML structure:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-bar">
</div>
```

and this css:

```
.menu-save {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%
    height: 20px;
}
```

With this CSS my expected output is that the `menu-bar` div goes underneath the whole menu, but what I'm currently getting is that `menu-bar` sits inside of `menu`, at the top of it. What CSS am I missing?

Comment: Go research “containing floats”.

Comment: It's already underneath, check here : https://jsfiddle.net/himstar/7vja0odg/2/ , or if you need side wise then add this css- .menu, .menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
    width: 260px;
}

Answer (score 1):

I think
use `clear: both` CSS property to avoid the floating problem

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="menu-bar">
```

In Css add this one

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```